# Generate multiple unique strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, unique

For my project, I have to generate a list of unique strings.
Everything works fine, but my problem is that it is very slow at the end.
I've tried using Parallel-Loops, but I found out that my `ConcurrentBag<T>`, which I was using, is also slow.
Now I'm using a simple for-loop and `List<T>` and it is now a little bit faster, but also really slow.

Here's my code:

```
private List<string> Generate(int start, int end, bool allowDupes)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var generator = new StringGenerator(LowerCase, UpperCase, Digits, NumberOfCharacters);
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb;
            while (true)
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (var j = 0; j < NumberOfSegments; j++)
                {
                    sb.Append(generator.GenerateRandomString());
                    if (j < NumberOfSegments - 1)
                    {
                        sb.Append(Delimiter);
                    }
                }
                if (!allowDupes)
                {
                    if (list.Contains(sb.ToString()))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            list.Add(sb.ToString());
            GeneratedStringCount = i + 1;
        }
        return new List<string>(list);
    }
```

I've also talked to my teacher and he would use the same algorithm for generating these strings.
Do you know a better solution? (The `GenerateRandomString()` Method in `StringGenerator` is simple and does not consume much performance.  `list.Contains(xy)` is consuming alot of resources. [Performance Analysis in Visual Studio])

Comment: whats the point of start and end?  It looks like a simple count of how many you want.  And why `return new List(list)` instead of `return list`?

Comment: What are the constraints on the content of these strings?

Comment: try using a HashSet<string> instead a List<string> this should improve Performance aspecially if you need a huge number of strings

Comment: @Jonesy Well start and end are used in the following way: If you have already generated X Strings, but you need to generate more, your "start" has the `list.Count` value instead of calculating the difference.

@MichaelGoldshteyn Could you please explain what you mean with constraints?

@ReneNiediek Yeah I ned a lot of strings (>100k), maybe a HashSet is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.Contains` is slow.  Use a `HashSet` instead.

```
private List<string> Generate(int start, int end, bool allowDupes)
{
    var strings = new HashSet<string>();
    var list = new List<string>();
    var generator = new StringGenerator(LowerCase, UpperCase, Digits, NumberOfCharacters);
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string randomString = GetRandomString();
            if (allowDupes || strings.Add(randomString))
            {
                list.Add(randomString);
                break;
            }
        }
        GeneratedStringCount = i + 1;
    }
    return new List<string>(list);
}

private string GetRandomString()
{
    var segments = Enumerable.Range(1, NumberOfSegments)
        .Select(_ => generator.GenerateRandomString());
    var result = string.Join(Delimeter, segments);
    return result;
}
```

This still has the chance for slow performance, but you could remedy that with a smart `GenerateRandomString` function.

Comment: Thanks, now it is a lot faster. (~32sec for 1 million strings) I'll try to optimize my `GenerateRandomString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String GenerateEightCode( int codeLenght, Boolean isCaseSensitive)
    {
        char[] chars = GetCharsForCode(isCaseSensitive);
        byte[] data = new byte[1];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        data = new byte[codeLenght];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(codeLenght);
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            sb.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
        }

        string key = sb.ToString();

        if (codeLenght == 8)
            key = key.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + key.Substring(4, 4);
        else if (codeLenght == 16)
            key = key.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + key.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + key.Substring(8, 4) + "-" + key.Substring(12, 4);

        return key.ToString();
    }

    private static char[] GetCharsForCode(Boolean isCaseSensitive)
    {
        // all - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890
        char[] chars = new char[58];
        if (isCaseSensitive)
        {
            chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789".ToCharArray();//počet unikátních kombinací 4 - 424 270, 8 - 1 916 797 311, 16 - 7.99601828013E+13
        }
        else
        {
            chars = new char[35];
            chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789".ToCharArray();//počet unikátních kombinací 4 - 52 360, 8 - 23 535 820, 16 - 4 059 928 950
        }

        return chars;
    }
```